# Maximum consecutive row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I am very new to SQL. I have two tables related to two player Tennis Game

Table 1 Name: matches # match information

```
tourney_id  tourney_name    surface tourney_date  mid winnner_id  loser_id  score   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"2019-0300" "Luxembourg"    "Hard"  "2019-10-14"  270   201504  201595  "5-7 6-1 6-3"
"2019-0300" "Luxembourg"    "Hard"  "2019-10-14"  271   201514  201426  "6-3 6-4"
"2019-0300" "Luxembourg"    "Hard"  "2019-10-14"  272   201697  211901  "6-2 7-6(4)"
"2019-0300" "Luxembourg"    "Hard"  "2019-10-14"  273   201620  211539  "6-1 6-0"
"2019-0300" "Luxembourg"    "Hard"  "2019-10-14"  274   214981  203564  "6-2 7-6(2)"
```

Table 2: players #information about the players

```
playerid  First Name    Last Name   Country
--------------------------------------------
200001     Martina      Hingis        SUI
200002     Mirjana      Lucic         CRO
200003     Justine      Henin         BEL
```

You can find complete table contents [table1-matches](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHglO3DkZPDFvqHH-jJYDbYh3jylo2-C/view?usp=sharing)

I need to find out which player(s) won the highest number of matches in a row?

I tired this SQL query using window function but could not succeed

```sql
select 
    *,
    count(tourney_id) over (partition by winner_id),
    count(tourney_id) over (partition by tourney_date)
from 
    matches
order by 
    tourney_date
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't tag spam, just tag the RDBMS you are really using, not 3 completely different ones.

Comment: Seems like a job for CTE as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117629/7034621

Comment: I see no tourney_date column in the matches table.

Comment: updated the table with all columns

Comment: The sample data contains no consecutive wins. In any case, what you describe is called the `gaps and islands` problem. You're looking for *islands* of the same `winner_id` value.

Comment: I have added the table complete details here

Comment: Instead of count you should use row_number function : select winnner_id, tourney_date, max(RwNum) as ConsecutiveWins from (select 
    *,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY winner_id,tourney_date ORDER BY tourney_date) as RwNum from matches)tab group by winnner_id, tourney_date,

Answer (score 1):

this is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, with the added complication that we first need to unpivot the wins and losses in order to get the start of each island.

We can use `LAG` to check the previous match for each player. Then a windowed count gives us a number for each group of wins.

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT
      v.status,
      v.id,
      m.tourney_date,
      StartOfGroup = CASE WHEN LAG(v.status, 1, '.')
              OVER (PARTITION BY v.id ORDER BY m.tourney_date) <> v.status THEN 1 END
    FROM matches m
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      ('W', winnner_id),
      ('L', loser_id)
    ) v(status, id)
),
Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY v.id
                ORDER BY m.tourney_date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM PrevValues v
    WHERE v.status = 'W'
),
PerGroup AS (
    SELECT
      v.id,
      TotalWins = COUNT(*)
    FROM Groups g
    GROUP BY
      g.id,
      g.GroupId
)
SELECT
  p.id,
  MaxConsecutiveWins = MAX(TotalWins)
FROM PerGroup p
GROUP BY
  p.id;
```