# Find rows with consecutive dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it possible to know which customer came at the bar 3 consecutive days? (john in my case)

Thanks in advance

| Name | Age | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 12 | 2021-12-01 | 20 |
| John | 19 | 2021-12-01 | 10 |
| Jack | 17 | 2021-13-01 | 7 |
| John | 19 | 2021-13-01 | 8 |
| John | 19 | 2021-14-01 | 17 |

Comment: Yes, that's possible, what have you tried to find the answer?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117179/sql-count-consecutive-days

Comment: I've tried: SELECT Name FROM Customer GROUP BY Name HAVING MAX(Date)-MIN(Date)=2days and COUNT(Date)=3

Comment: Your query returns `John` (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e5d5ddf91c319b5d1b250a453c88e0a)), so it is unclear what your question is.

Comment: BTW:   A proper date format is given in [YYYY-MM-DD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), not in `YYYY-DD-MM` as those Americans tend to do , to make it readable to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

so I would approach this by

```
SELECT FROM Table
    LEFT JOIN Table As PrevDay on PrevDay.Customer = Table.Customer 
        AND PrevDay.date = DATEADD(DAY,-1,Table.Date)
    LEFT JOIN Table AS NextDay on NextDay,Customer = Table.Customer 
        AND NextDay.Date = DATEADD(DATE,1,Table.Date)
WHERE PrevDay.Customer is not NULL 
AND NextDay.Customer is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data type of the column `Date` is `DATE` you can use a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.Name = t1.Name AND ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.Date, t2.Date)) = 1
GROUP BY t1.Name, t1.Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Date) = 2;
```

Or, a more scalable solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.Name = t1.Name AND t2.Date BETWEEN t1.Date AND t1.Date + INTERVAL 2 DAY
GROUP BY t1.Name, t1.Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Date) = 3;
```

You can remove `DISTINCT` from `COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Date)` if the combination of `Name` and `Date` is unique in the table.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b8dd43c3c5cf00b758278947f59dbc4).