# Create a count of consecutive days when condition is met psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a query to get the consecutive days by the data dates.

Using this table as sample:

```
 id_used |      ref_date       
---------+---------------------
   1     | 2021-02-01 00:00:00
   1     | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 
   1     | 2021-09-02 00:00:00 
   1     | 2021-09-03 00:00:00
```

My return should be 3 (The 3 last rows).

Comment: is this same with your questions ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117179/sql-count-consecutive-days